# How to change timezone in current shell session in Redhat

Tags: linux, csh, timezone

`ls -lt` shows time in PDT, I want to change it to `Asia/Singapore` in the current session. I tried `set TZ=Asia/Singapore` But it's showing the same time on `ls -lt`.

How to do it?

Comment: `set TZ=Asia/Singapore`? Are you using (t)csh?

Comment: Could you please confirm what shell you use as login shell? What does `echo "$SHELL"` say?

Comment: echo "$SHELL" shows this -->  /bin/csh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `TZ` environment variable in `csh`, use

```
sentenv TZ Asia/Singapore
```

Answer (score 3):

For the current shell session, use the TZ environment variable by running the command:

```
export TZ=Asia/Singapore
```

For this change to persist beyond this shell session, you'll need to change the file that stores the time zone. In Red Hat-based systems, that's the **/etc/localtime** file. You'll want to remove it and replace it with the correct timezone. Other timezones are present in the **/usb/share/zoneinfo** directory.

First:

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
```

Then:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore /etc/localtime
```

Running `date` should give you the right output now.

Comment: it says export: Command not found

Comment: It sounds like you might not be using bash then. So try `set TZ=Asia/Singapore` or `setenv TZ Asia/Singapore`.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to change timezone is to use shell variable TZ. You can do it with single line command as below :

```
bash -c "export TZ=Asia/Singapore"
```

This timezone setting will be available for current shell only from where you are exporting this TZ variable.

Comment: I tried , it says export: Command not found.

Comment: @Codeformer I have updated export bash command. Try this code
`bash -c "export TZ=Asia/Singapore"`

Comment: You can't set an environment variable in a child process (your `bash -c` shell) and expect it to be set in the current interactive shell.

Comment: Yes, you can. Checkout this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144965/2339542]

Comment: @Ehtesham That answer _shows that it can't be done_.  Sorry.